# Best practices for Google Searching from Web Page

Tags: search, web, google-search

I have a webpage that has a text area that when is submitted will open a new tab with their query input into google search automatically to give our page Google access. My question being what are the best practices for doing this without any chance of Google thinking our company is spamming the search engine?

Currently it is as simple as opening a new tab to

`"https://www.google.com/search?q=" + their_encoded_query`.

Is there anything I should be keeping in mind for a business' interaction with Google Search that I should be aware of?